# White Bead on an indoor pepper plant

Tags: pests, peppers

I moved my pepper plants indoors to overwinter them and one has recently developed some small white beads on the leaves that I am unfamiliar with. Which pest am I dealing with and how best can I handle them to keep my peppers healthy?

Located in Denver, CO. The pepper plants are MadHatter and NuMex Suave.

[image]

Comment: I believe they're whitefly eggs

Answer (score 1):

[image]Found this on the net. Could be Aphid eggs. you could check out this link https://gardenerspath.com/how-to/disease-and-pests/aphids/